# File upload using html ajax php

Tags: php, html, ajax

Previously i have performed submitting html page's data to php page by ajax using get or post method.Now i want to know suppose my html page have an input tag of type file in following way

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" />
<input type="button" id="btn_crop" onclick="btbn_click()" />
```

Now i want to perform that after clicking the button the file will be transferred to "crop.php" by ajax.I don't want to use the ajax file upload cause i wish to perform the cropping before storing the file in server hard disk page.Now can any body give me suggestion about this?

Comment: For doing this, On click of button store the image file on your server and call `crop.php` and load this image file in this file and crop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this [Nettuts+ tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) helpful. That's for uploading files with AJAX. Now, when the file gets transferred to your server, it is automatically stored in a temporary directory, from where you can move it after cropping it and whatsoever. If you want, you can also try deleting it afterwards, I don't know.

Try the GD functions for cropping. A good search will do the trick.

Hope I helped.